# Error when transferring code

Tags: java

I'm writing code for class, and the code works fine when I run it in Dr. Java in class. However when I input it for grading, I get an error that reads:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Main.main(Main.java:247)
    at Ideone.assertRegex(Main.java:94)
    at Ideone.test(Main.java:42)
    at Ideone.main(Main.java:29)
```

I have no idea what this means, we haven't covered this sort of thing and I am not a very experienced programmer, sorry. My code is as follows;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int indexFirst = 0;
        int indexSecond = 0;
        int[] first = new int[10000];
        int[] second = new int[10000];

        System.out.println("Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");
        do {int value = scanner.nextInt();
            if (value < 0) {
                break;
            }
            first[indexFirst++] = value;
        } while(true);

        System.out.println("Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");
        do {int value = scanner.nextInt();
            if (value <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            second[indexSecond++] = value;
        } while(true);
        System.out.println("First Array:");
        for (int i = 0; i < indexFirst; i++) {
            System.out.print(first[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");

        System.out.println("Second Array:");
        for (int i = 0; i < indexSecond; i++) {
            System.out.print(second[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int i = 1; i < indexFirst; i++) {
            if (first[i-1] > first[i] ) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Array not in correct order");
                return;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < indexSecond; i++) {
            if (second[i-1] > second[i] ) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Array not in correct order");
                return;
            }
        }

        int[] merged = new int[indexFirst + indexSecond];
        int curIdx1 = 0;
        int curIdx2 = 0;
        for(int mergedIdx = 0; mergedIdx < merged.length; mergedIdx++) {
            if (curIdx2 == indexSecond) {
                merged[mergedIdx] = first[curIdx1++];
            } else if (curIdx1 == indexFirst) {
                merged[mergedIdx] = second[curIdx2++];
            } else if (first[curIdx1] < second[curIdx2]) {
                merged[mergedIdx] = first[curIdx1++];
            } else {
                merged[mergedIdx] = second[curIdx2++];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Merged Array:");
        for (int i = 0; i < merged.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(merged[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has any input on how to fix this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: "at Main.main(Main.java:247)" -- Which line is line 247 in `Main`?

Comment: When you compile this and run it, does it work fine regardless of whether you enter 1 number more than 1 number?  I'm wondering if nextInt() is getting called and there is not another number.

Comment: xec86 - When I enter six 3's for example. 3 3 3 3 3 3 and then 0 to end it, it works fine.

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting errors on lines 94 and 247. Those lines don't exist. This program is complete as is. Your code doesn't seem to be [verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Gendarme I have not posted here before. How would I fix that?

Comment: *"Ensure that the example actually reproduces the problem!"* Does this code reproduce the problem? I can't reproduce it. What inputs are you giving, and how are you getting errors on lines 94 and 247 when those lines are nonexistent?

Comment: *I have no idea what this means, we haven't covered this sort of thing*: that shouldn't stop you from using google, or to open the javadoc of the exception and of Scanner, to try understanding by yourself. All developers do that every single day.